# Is there a get_form helper method in django / how to call an instance of a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Django has a helper method called "get_model" which gets you an instance of a model given the app name and model name. Is there a similar method for getting forms?

The reason is that I'm trying to implement the following code

```
def create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    blank_form= request.session['form'] 
    form_request = blank_form(request.POST)
```

What this code is trying to do is the following: It checks the session to see what form the user is currently looking at and stores that form in the variable "blank_form". I'm trying to create another instance of the form (in another variable called "form_request") that is bound by the data the user entered -- However, I'm getting an error that blank_form is not callable.

Is there a way to go about fixing this?

Comment: How do you store the form in the session ? If I'm not mistaken and you assign request.session['form'] a form that is not instantiated it should be no problem instantiating it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
blank_form = request.session['form'] 
new_form = blank_form.__class__(...)
```

I've never tried doing anything this way though, so no guarantees!